# Length of String Returned by The Network Stream is Always 8193

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, networkstream, trim

I'm sending a string across the network and everytime I check the side receiving the string, it always tells me that the length of the string received is `8193`. But when I try to assign a value before it is displayed in the `MsgBox`, it returns the correct value. I tried trimming the string using `String.Trim(Chr(10))`*, `String.Trim(Chr(13))`, `String.Trim(ChrW(8193))` but to no avail.

Does anybody have any idea about this?

***Here's my code for the receiving side.***

```
Private Sub ChatConnectionTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ChatConnectionTimer.Tick

    Try
        Dim ConnectionStatus As String = String.Empty

        If CBool(chatClientSocket.Available) Then
            chatNetworkStream = chatClientSocket.GetStream()
            Dim ByteData(chatClientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
            chatNetworkStream.Read(ByteData, 0, CInt(chatClientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize))
            ConnectionStatus = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ByteData)

            MsgBox(ConnectionStatus.Length()) 'This part always return 8193

            If ConnectionStatus.Contains("Server is disconnected.") Then
                DisconnectChat()
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: So what does the string actually contain?

Comment: Just some short string messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ByteData buffer is always the size of ReceiveBufferSize. What you want to do is check how much .Read returned and use that as the length of the returned message.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Just one more thing, what if I decided to retrieve the index of a certain element on the string. How can I do that?

Comment: You don't define what "element" means, but generally you do result = stringVar.IndexOf("whatever")...